# Array within an other array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rest, api

I have an object of array ( form an API ), eatch object contains an array and i can't get access to the sub array:

Structure:

> Billing [date, totalPrice, {productList[product1,product2]}, ..., ..., {[...,...,...]},....,....,...,
>   {[...,...,...,]}]

My Model is:

```
export  class Billing {
  private _productsList: Array<InvoiceLine>;
  private _Date: Date;
  private _totalPrice: number;
}
```

Then I initialized an my array:

```
public AllBilling: Billing[] = [];
```

Then when I try to get my data from Blling Array it works.

```
for ( i = 0; i < this.AllBilling.length; i++){
     console.log(this.AllBilling);
}
```

But when I try to get `productsList` form my array it doesn't work.

```
for ( i = 0; i < this.Belling.length; i++){
     console.log(this.Belling[i]);

        for ( j = 0; j < this.AllBilling[i].productsList.length; i++){
          console.log(this.AllBilling[i].productsList[j]); }
}
```

It gives me the folowing error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

witch refer to `productsList.length`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yQsr.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several mistakes in this code

1. what you need to repeat is `AllBilling`, not `Belling`,
   `Belling` refers to a class, not a value
2. `_productsList` not `productsList`
3. If you want to access `productsList`, it should be
   `public`, not `private`

That's why it was not working.
Hope this help

Comment: Point 3 is not a *should*, it is just a suggestion, since javascript will still be able to access the field directly

Comment: It's correct. However, if you mark it as private, it'll throw an error when you build it, or even in the IDE. Since you use TypeScript, you should follow it, otherwise it doesn't make sense

Comment: and "should" is a suggestion, isn't it :D, not "must"

Comment: It will throw an error if you have the option –noEmitOnError